# Process a PHP File Before Including It

Tags: php, include, templating

I'm developing a PHP templating engine<sup>1</sup> and I want to allow PHP syntax alongside the templating syntax. My process currently is to compile the template into a php file (convert all template syntax to PHP), store it to disk and then load it using `include`<sup>2</sup>. The compilation will only take place if the original template has been modified or if no compilation has ever been made.

However, there are a few issues with this approach:

1. I cannot be sure whether I have enough permissions to create new files
2. Creating and saving files is a costly process

Is there another approach to this?

For example, the following code:

```
<ul>
    <?php forach( $list as $item ): ?> 
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Would be compiled to:

```
<ul>
    <?php forach( $list as $item ): ?> 
        <li><?php echo $item ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

---

[1] *I know that there are hundreds of those, but this one is suppose to be the answer to special cases.*  **The goal is to enhance PHP's built in templating engine, rather than replace it altogether like other engines.**
[2] *Note that I do not want to use `eval` for this as it is both costly and dangerous.*

Comment: Sounds to me like it boils down to "How to implement caching effectively" - the compiler result would be the cached version of the source script.

Comment: Perhaps, unless there is a way to process the file prior to including it (without having to save a temp file), in which case I won't need to cache anything

Comment: process before including? `exec('php file.php')`

Comment: @Dagon That's interesting. What is the performance impact of that vs. a simple include?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "process before include". You want to check whether the file has been changed since it has been cached, that's clear. You _could possibly_ do that via [filemtime](http://docs.php.net/filemtime). Maybe you could narrow (or broaden,who knows ;-)) the question by describing what kind of setup/prerequisites you would accept. Would "Setup an inode watcher and have it compile+store the result in memcache" be an acceptable answer? Or "Implement an (php) interface to upload the templates and start the compilation once the new version is uploaded"? And if not, why?

Comment: @VolkerK I want to convert the template's syntax into basic PHP syntax, then load it using php's include. I added an example.

Comment: i dont really see the merit in this approach at all - good luck ;)

Comment: @Dagon I updated the example. The goal is to be able to use PHP's syntax and add new features to it, instead of rewriting the whole syntax from scratch

Comment: @VolkerK I guess if it is possible to guarantee that the calling script has enough file permissions to create new files, the initial approach could work.

Comment: why would you not start with the 2nd example? tempting allows people with little knowledge to add code, your already adding code.

Comment: " I want to convert the template's syntax into basic PHP syntax, then load it using php's include." - Yeah, yeah, yeah, that much is clear ;-) My question is just how general or specific the solution can/must be and what kinds of constraints on the server-setup are feasible for you. If it's just for you/your company/a specific project you can do virtually anything for speed - up to modifying an existing opcode cache to allow for custom compiler runs. If on the other hand you want to get it out into the wild options will probably much more limited.

Comment: @Dagon I think the ultimate goal of templating, for me at least, is to seperate logic from presentation. The above example is just a very basic one.

Comment: @VolkerK good question - no, it is not just for me. This might be used for WordPress themes, where there is no control over the user's setup.

Comment: @Dagon of course, basic logic is a must for any templating engine, you can't avoid it completely, but the more complex logic is extracted.

Comment: Maybe you want to change the question title to something like "opcache with custom (pre-)compiler run" to attract more experts on that matter. Since that's not me, I will just keep this question in my watchlist, in case no such expert shows up ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK I appreciate your help! Isn't opcache an extension? I don't think it is installed by default, which is a problem in this case

Comment: Oh, you're right. I meant "opcache" as a generic term for "opcode cache" - and even that wouldn't necessarily be correct as you might be content with saving the php source transformation, not the actual byte/op- code ;-)